# What is Ubuntu Single?

Tags: single-sign-on

Have received a password for Ubuntu Single and I don't know what Ubuntu Single is? Can someone enlighten me?

Thanks

Comment: Er please post your email (of course left out your personal details)

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean Ubuntu Single Sign-On. This is a login you can use for many other Ubuntu related websites and services such as [Ubuntu One](http://one.ubuntu.com/), the [Ubuntu Loco Directory](http://loco.ubuntu.com/) and [Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/). You can also use this login to write reviews in Ubuntu Software Center.

Sometimes you will be asked to log in to Launchpad. Just use the same username and password with Launchpad and it will work as if you were using the Single Sign-On service. You can see all of the websites you have authenticated with at https://login.ubuntu.com/.

Comment: I'm going completely by memory for the Launchpad thing, so please do correct me if I'm wrong :)

Answer (score 0):

Quoting from the [community help page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SingleSignOn)

> SSO is a name for a collection of technologies that allows network users to provide a single set of credentials for all network services. In a properly configured SSO environment, a user's desktop environment can migrate seamlessly between computers, and access to shared resources such as file systems and printers can be managed with ease.

For more and detailed information, Go to this page: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SingleSignOn